# How to mock the "+" operator in python (specifically datetime.date + datetime.timedelta)

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

I have working through some date mocking issues in Django, and have the final hurdle (I hope) is the following situation. I have a FakeDate class, which derives from `datetime.date`, which it mocks out.

The FakeDate class works as expected, however I get a problem when adding a `datetime.timedelta` to the FakeDate, in that it returns a genuine `datetime.date`, rather than the mock. This is important as elsewhere in a third party library there is an `isinstance(value, datetime.date)` check, which will always fail when using timedelta.

```
>>> import mock
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> class FakeDate(datetime.date):
...     @classmethod
...     def today(cls):
...         return cls(1999, 12, 31)
...
>>> FakeDate.today()
FakeDate(1999, 12, 31)
>>> FakeDate(2000, 1, 1)
FakeDate(2000, 1, 1)
>>> FakeDate(1999, 12, 31) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
```

I want the FakeDate + timedelta addition to return a FakeDate object rather than a datetime.date object - which I imagine involves patching the timedelta somehow - but how / where can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `__add__` method to your `FakeDate()` class:

```
class FakeDate(datetime.date):
     @classmethod
     def today(cls):
         return cls(1999, 12, 31)
     def __add__(self, other):
         res = super(FakeDate, self).__add__(other)
         return type(self)(res.year, res.month, res.day)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class FakeDate(datetime.date):
...      @classmethod
...      def today(cls):
...          return cls(1999, 12, 31)
...      def __add__(self, other):
...          res = super(FakeDate, self).__add__(other)
...          return type(self)(res.year, res.month, res.day)
... 
>>> FakeDate.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
FakeDate(2000, 1, 1)
```

Note that you can simply delegate the actual adding to the `datetime.date` class here; all we need to do is convert the result back to a `FakeDate()` instance.

Comment: Wow - I was still editing the question! Thank you. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define an `__add__` method in your `FakeDate` class -- it's the method that controls the behavior of the `+` operator.

```
import datetime

class FakeDate(datetime.date):
    @classmethod
    def today(cls):
        return cls(1999, 12, 31)

    def __add__(self, delta):
        # Create a datetime.date object so we don't need to do any calculations
        new_date = super(FakeDate, self).__add__(delta)
        # Then convert it to FakeDate.
        return FakeDate(new_date.year, new_date.month, new_date.day)

# Returns a FakeDate for 2000-01-01
FakeDate.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Note that this only handles the `fakedate + timedelta` case. If you want `timedelta + fakedate` to also return an instance of `FakeDate`, you'll need to define the `__radd__` method as well (same code as `__add__`).

For more information on the `__magic_methods__` associated with operators, see http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types .

Comment: Thanks Max - unfortunately Martijn got in there first, but have upvoted your answer (as the __radd__ comment was really useful).